# Intel/Altera Quartus: How to force the compiled build up to date to avoid a recompile?

Tags: compilation, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I have an already compiled FPGA build in my workspace. 
When I open it in Quartus (14.1) the tools often decide it's no longer up to date. They may even be right about this, but I don't care.
I just want to open the netlist viewer and look at some internals, but Quartus insists on recompiling the project (1 hour in my current situation).

Sometimes things get "poked" due to a TCL script that was running in my startup,
or perhaps an SVN checkout touched a file. 
The thing is I don't care, I just want to re-examine already compiled results. I don't want it to build anything.

This is one of those annoyances where I wish I'd had time to set up a Makefile, then I could just instruct Make to force the results up to date, but, them's the breaks..

I did some googling, and stack overflow hunting, but haven't seen a solution yet..

Comment: I also encountered this problem. At least, I only needed to view report, which was possible with "Compilation Report" button.